# Read from a file opened with O_WRONLY

Tags: file-io, unix

Is it possible to read from a file which is opened using `open` system call with `O_WRONLY` flag in Unix?. If it is possible then what does Write Only (O_WRONLY) mean??

Thanks,
LinuxPenseur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just not with the file descriptor returned from that `open()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Duh. Oh course write-only means exactly that — write ONLY.

Comment: But i was able to open the file for reading.!!!..I used some editor to open and it did not complain? But when i tried to read it using the read system call, it returned some junk value. So what is the inference from this?

Comment: Just because *one* program opens the file WRONLY and gets a write-only filedescriptor does not that mean another program cannot read from it by using another filedescriptor that was opened with RDONLY/RDWR. As for junk: well, check read()s error message and stop printing an uninitialized buffer.